# How to check for valid $PATH directories, and output them telling whether each one is valid or not?

Tags: bash, directory, path, string

Ok so I got this:

```
check="${PATH//:/'\n'}"
```

The above gets me each path in a simplified manner, and formats it nicely into a variable. Now how do I check each line for existence, and state that for each line in combination with an echo (I think I would use echo.)?

I know it probably involves a for or while loop, but I'm not sure how to do this.

**BASH** only answers please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while read -d: dir
do
    [ -d "$dir" ] || echo "Missing: $dir"
done <<<"${PATH%:}:"
```

`read -d: dir` reads input into variable `dir`, breaking the input at `:`.

`[ -d "$dir" ]` tests for the existence of the directory

`||` only executes the statement that follows if the preceding statement returned false.

`<<<"${PATH%:}:"` provides input to the loop using a *here-string*.  The form `"${PATH%:}:"` makes sure that one `:` follows the PATH string.  This is done in two steps.  The first uses *suffix removal*,  `${PATH%:}`, to remove a trailing `:` from the PATH if there is one.  Secondly, one colon is added.

Comment: With bash 4.2.8 the last path in $PATH is ignored.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks.  I believe the updated answer fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

This combines the best parts of the three answers<sup>1</sup>
existing at the time of this posting
(sort answers by “oldest” if you want to see which ones those are)
and adds a slightly different way of doing [what John1024 is doing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243764/80216):

```
IFS=: read -a path_components <<< "$PATH"
for dir in "${path_components[@]}"
do
    printf "%s\t-> " "$dir"
    if [ -d "$dir" ]
    then
        echo "Exists."
    else
        echo "Missing!!!!"
    fi
done
```

`IFS=:` does essentially the same thing as John’s `read -d:`;
it breaks the input at `:` (and not at space or tab);
so, like John’s answer,
this handles directories with whitespace in their names correctly. 
`read -a path_components` reads the input into an **a**rray;
`"${path_components[@]"` expands to a list of the members of the array. 
Note that `echo "$dir"` can be dangerous
if `$dir` begins with a **`-`** or contains a `\`. 
(Admittedly, these with be rare for directory names in `$PATH`.) 
`printf "$dir"` can be dangerous if `$dir` contains a `%`.
_______
<sup>1</sup> one of which was deleted as I composed this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way out also:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n")

for x in $arr
do
    echo -n "$x"
     if [ -d "$x" ];then
        echo " -> Exists"
     else
         echo -e " -> \e[31mMissing!!!!\e[0m"
     fi
done
```

With `arr=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n")` you split the directories in a variable and the `echo -e` add color red to the display to draw attention to.

The output will be like follows:

> /usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin -> Exists
>
> /usr/local/sbin -> Exists
>
> /usr/local/bin -> Exists
>
> /sbin -> Exists
>
> /bin -> Exists
>
> /usr/sbin -> Exists
>
> /usr/bin -> Exists
>
> /root/bin -> Missing!!!

Comment: This will fail if `$PATH` contains space(s) (or tabs).  This is unusual in Unix/Linux *per se*, but common in Cygwin, where the Cygwin/Unix `$PATH` incorporates the Windows `%PATH%` and so will include directories like `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft Games`.